# Making all combinations with certain arguments in python

Tags: python

So im trying to make a thing that makes all combinations and then prints it, with this

```
import random
import string


def randomString(stringLength=3):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(stringLength))

print(randomString(3)+str(random.randint(10, 99))+(randomString(3)))
```

But i cant get it to work...
I want it to look like this, so it print all the combinations.
aaa00aaa
aaa00aab
aaa00aac
aaa00aad

And so on

Comment: What do you mean by `to get it work`?

Comment: Like ehm, to get it to make all possible combinations with
```
 (randomString(3)+str(random.randint(10, 99))+(randomString(3)))
```

Comment: So it prints aaa00aaa aaa00aab aaa00aac aaa00aad and so on

Comment: Your existing code will only print one line and it will be randomly generated. If you run the code again you'll get another random line, maybe the same one. If you want to systematically work through all possible options you need completely different code.

Answer (score 0):

To make all possible combinations of letters you can use `product()` form `itertools`

```py
from itertools import product
import string
letters = string.ascii_lowercase
# repeat here sets the length of how many letters you want
all_combinations = product(letters, repeat=3)
new_arr = [''.join(x) for x in all_combinations]
# this new_arr will be an array of strings of all combinations
```

to me it doesn't look like you want to get a random int instead you want an increment number of some king of pattern.
***To print a random int***

```py
# continuing upper code
import random
# to print the patter you want you can use F-string if you have python 3.6 and up
# or you can use format()
# You also need loops two loops to print your strings
for first_part in new_arr:
    for second_part in new_arr:
        print(f"{first_part}{random.randint(0, 99)}{secondPart}") #using F-String
        print("{}{}{}".format(first_part, random.randint(0, 99), secondPart)) # using format

# If you want to increment numbers and reset and start from 0 again
# Basically you need the same thing with a few changes
# first use a variable that will change
i = 0
for first_part in new_arr:
    for second_part in new_arr:
        print(f"{first_part}{i}{secondPart}") #using F-String
        print("{}{}{}".format(first_part, i, secondPart)) # using format
        i += 1 #increment variable by one
        if i == 100:
            i = 0 #reset i back to 0
```

**Keep in mind that this will print 0 - 9 as one char only ex: aaa0aaa instead of aaa00aaa**

Comment: Nicolae does it also work with numbers, and if does, how to make it so make all combinations, and it have to be 3 letters 2 numbers 3 letters.?

Comment: It works with anything, but in your case you will have to use this array to and concatenate in a for loop with what you want, as if you give it numbers too it will create combinations including numbers but you want exact pattern of **[3-cahr 2-num 3-char]** this will yield a huge number of combinations

Comment: Can you explain when the 2 numbers will be incremented? as you can use two for loops to print desired string

Comment: Okay, but how do i set it up? In the coding... Im still a bit confused, and im not the best at coding.